# In Access VBA int(-0.005 * (10 ^ 6)) = -5001 Really

Tags: ms-access, vba

Consider this:

Text from the access VBA debug window:

```vb
? -0.005 * (10 ^ 6)
-5000 ' Which is as you would expect

? int(-5000)
-5000 ' Which is as you would expect

? int(-0.005 * (10 ^ 6))
-5001 ' Which is NOT what I expected 

? Int(-0.005 * 1000000)
-5001 ' Which is NOT what I expected
```

Here's the function I wrote which I expected to always round a number up to the number of decimal places shown.

Am I missing something.  Does anyone know ho I might write a function to do this?

```vb
    Public Function RoundItUp(AValue As Double, DecimalPlaces As Integer) As Variant
        '
        'Rounding up
        '
        'To round upwards towards the next highest number, take advantage of the way Int() rounds negative numbers downwards, like this:
        '    - Int( - [MyField])
        '
        'As shown above, Int(-2.1) rounds down to -3. Therefore this expression rounds 2.1 up to 3.
        '
        'To round up to the higher cent, multiply by -100, round, and divide by -100:
        '    Int(-100 * [MyField]) / -100

        Dim Multiplier As Long

        If DecimalPlaces <= 0 Then
            RoundItUp = Null
            Exit Function
        End If

        Multiplier = 10 ^ DecimalPlaces

        If AValue < 0 Then

            RoundItUp = Int(AValue)

        Else

            RoundItUp = -Int(-AValue * Multiplier) / Multiplier

        End If



    End Function
```

And more debug window text showing how I discovered the error:

```vb
? rounditup(0.005,6)
0.005001 

? -AValue *  Multiplier
-5000 

? Int(-AValue * Multiplier)
-5001 

? int(-5000)
-5000 

? Int((-AValue * Multiplier))
-5001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the Fix function - the issue is that you've got negative numbers so the idea of 'rounding up' changes.

Comment: In what ways?  Try to give full answers that allow OP and future users to understand the issue fully.   Including myself :-)

Comment: Thanks pointing me to find out more about fix which was all I needed to create a work around.  However, I think the above shows a access vba bug.  Info on fix can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh29swte(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is no bug here, but you use Double which will introduce errors.

Use Currency or Decimal instead:

```
? Int(-CCur(0.005) * 1000000)    
? Int(-CDec(0.005) * 1000000)
```

Returns 5000.

Comment: Yes I see.  Thanks.  So does this mean that in the intermediate window any  numbers are treated as double by functions like int().

Comment: Yes, you can be fooled this way, as you cannot Dim a variable here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

My function ened up looking like this:

```
    Public Function RoundItUp(AValue As Double, DecimalPlaces As Integer, Optional RoundNegativeValuesUp As Boolean = False) As Variant

        '
        'Rounding up
        '
        'To round upwards towards the next highest number, take advantage of the way Int() rounds negative numbers downwards, like this:
        '    - Int( - [MyField])
        '
        'As shown above, Int(-2.1) rounds down to -3. Therefore this expression rounds 2.1 up to 3.
        '
        'To round up to the higher cent, multiply by -100, round, and divide by -100:
        '    Int(-100 * [MyField]) / -100
        '
        ' Note Decimal values must be used not double ones!  See below

        Dim Multiplier As Long

        If DecimalPlaces <= 0 Then
            RoundItUp = Null
            Exit Function
        End If

        Multiplier = 10 ^ DecimalPlaces


        ' Both the Int and Fix functions remove the fractional part of Number and return the resulting integer value.
        ' The difference between Int and Fix functions is that if Number is negative,
        ' Int returns the first negative integer less than or equal to Number, whereas
        ' Fix returns the first negative integer greater than or equal to Number.
        '
        ' For example, Int converts -8.4 to -9, and Fix converts -8.4 to -8.
        '
        ' Fix(number) is equivalent to Sign(number) * Int(Abs(number)).

        If AValue < 0 And RoundNegativeValuesUp Then

            RoundItUp = Fix(CDec(AValue * Multiplier)) / Multiplier

        Else

            RoundItUp = Int(CDec(AValue * Multiplier)) / Multiplier

        End If



    End Function
```